# Git - how to delete all but previous 2 (or n) version of files?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a test repo in which we do a bunch of changes to pass on to production team. This has grown a bit - and we would like to trim the repo. Since we have copies in other clients - we would like to

- for all files in a given directory - delete all but previous 3 versions of the file and remove any references from the repo.

I would like to do this dir by dir. essentially remove from git/repo/disk any version older than n-3 for a given file or files in a directory.

thanks

Comment: Git works by versions of the _repository_, not really versions of each _file_. It would be pretty easy to remove all but the last n versions of the repo. But if you want to preserve the last n versions of each file, what would that look like. If a commit originally had 10 files changed in it, but with your pruning algorithm, because 9 of them were subsequently changed (n+2) times, you would preserve that commit but now containing only one file. The commit message on that commit would be deceiving.  Anyway, how big is big? Git does a good job of compressing.

Comment: the repo is hosted - and is about 3GB. mostly images - which is why we would like to do this.. t

Answer (score 1):

You could create a **shallow** clone of this repo. Shallow means that you can have the last n commits (commits that are per the whole tree and not per file).
`git clone --depth 2 git@your.server.com:dir/repo.git shallow_repo`
Note that that if you want this clone to be as a server you may want to add `--mirror`

You can also do this from the same machine using local directory:
`git clone --depth 2 file:///path/to/repo/ shallow_repo`
Note that doing this from local directory may bring only current branch, and not all of them.